# Java Program That Reveals Hidden Password

Tags: java, jpasswordfield

I want to make a simple Java program that reveals a password copied from a browser or another application that is hidden in the form of asterisks.

I wrote some code but it doesn't work!

When I copy the password from Facebook password field for example, and paste it to the JPasswordField on my program. And then transform it to normal text, it shows me wrong output (in fact, it gives me my class name which is weird)

However, when I copy any normal text and paste it into the JPasswordField and then get the text, it gives the correct normal text back!

So why isn't it working? I'm sorry if my question seems stupid a little. I'm new to programming and especially with practical programs.
How can I make it work? :D

Thanks in advance,
Here's the code:

```
class PasswordViewer extends JFrame {
    JPasswordField field = new JPasswordField(20);
    JButton btn = new JButton("OK");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    char[] s;

    PasswordViewer() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(btn);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(panel);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                s = field.getPassword();
                findPass();
            }
        });
    }
    void findPass() {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            str += s[i];
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str, "PasswordViewer",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordViewer passview = new PasswordViewer();
        passview.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you copied not exactly the text;but,rather,the asteriskised version of it which doesn't work that way!

Comment: I don't think you can see passwords like that.

Comment: You can not copy password from facebook. If you paste it to text editor you will see it.

Comment: Most morden browsers don't let the value of password field be copied. What you are pasting is what ever you scussefully copied before you tried to copy password.

Comment: @shekharsuman, I know that! But I thought you would be able to help?!

Comment: @Price-2-3 years ago I also tried the same foolish thing! So similar---ha ha ha. But,it doesn't work that way!

Comment: I think there must be a way to figure it out.
I'm just new to this kind of stuff.
When I realize it. I will let you guys know...

Comment: @shekharsuman, just because it doesn't work, doesn't mean it's stupid!

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91, Oh, you're right! I thought I was copying the password. Apparently, something was saved and that's why when I pasted, it actually pasted something. So do you think it would work if I'm actually able to copy???

Comment: If you are able to copy it. It will work. but mostly, I think almost every website doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot copy from a browser's password field as @ankitkatiyar91 pointed out.
I was mistaken.
This question is meaningless until you can find a way to copy the password from the browser's password field.